# org-mode fails to export to html: Trying results in a mumamo message

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I can export fine from emacs org-mode to PDF, etc.
But when I try using M-x or C-c e  to export to html, I get nothing but the following comment, which appears in the Message buffer:

mumamo-get-major-mode-setup: fun-var-sym=mumamo-eval-in-html-mode, use-major-entry=(html-mode (mumamo-eval-in-html-mode mumamo-def-eval-in-html-mode mumamo-kw-eval-in-html-mode))

I don't know what any of that means, and I can find nothing about how to fix this on the interweb!

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: I don't use mumamo, but do you have the 'htmlize' package installed?

Comment: I think so. In fact, everything works fine (ie exporting HTML from org-mode is perfect) until I put "(setq org-export-with-smart-quotes t)" in my custom.el.  But I want that setting for LaTeX expoerting.